# Git for windows seems to automatically fall back to credential helper "manager" if everything else fails. How do I prevent this?

Tags: php, windows, git

I'm trying to integrate a custom web page with git. In my PHP scripts, I use the option "-c credential.helper="store --file=..." so that the web page does not stop and wait for a password to be input. The User ID is specifically designated for automated tasks like this. As part of the web interface, I have some code that will update the credentials file when the password expires.

During development, when I issue the git commands at the windows command prompt (the "terminal" for you *NIX readers :) they all work fine. However, when I put the commands inside my PHP script and run it via the web server, they fail. I've managed to capture the output of the git task, and it's waiting for someone to type in a user ID.

It seems that git on windows will automatically drop back to the "manager" helper, if all other mechanisms fail. The following sequence of commands illustrates this:

```
C:\TFS\Train>git config --get --show-origin credential.helper

C:\TFS\Train>type .git\.git_web_credentials
http://Promote5:[.....]@tocgnxt1pv%3a8080

C:\TFS\Train>git -c credential.helper="store --file=C:\TFS\Train\.git\.git_credentials" tag -a -m "Testing tags from the command line" Who_created_this_tag2

C:\TFS\Train>git show Who_created_this_tag2
tag Who_created_this_tag2
Tagger: JimHyslop <jim.hyslop@xxx.xxx>
Date:   Wed Dec 6 18:13:27 2017 -0500

[... remainder of output elided ...]

C:\TFS\Train>git --version
git version 2.13.0.windows.1
```

As you can see, the "tagger" line indicates that I'm the one who applied the tag.

I've even tried deleting the credentials file completely, but it still falls back to using my identity.

Is there any way to suppress this automatic fall back to using my Windows credentials? It's making it very difficult to debug my PHP script: I never know from the command prompt whether the command succeeded because it was able to use the credentials file, or because it fell back to using my own ID (which the web service cannot do).

Edit to add: The password is actually in the credentials file, I masked it out. The file was initially created by entering the ID and password from a Cygwin shell, which is running a slightly newer version of git: 2.15.0. I'm running a WAMP stack for my web service.

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation, I realized that the 'tagger' line is pulled from the configuration information under the [user] section. The user information shown in the log is unrelated to the authorization/credentials method.

The real question is: why is git ignoring the command-line option "-c credential.helper="? Or, if it's not ignoring the option, how can I figure out exactly what is failing with the credential helper?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the solution I came up with was to write a custom credential manager, as outlined [at git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)